# Wrong coordinates for UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton, storyboard, coordinates, bounds

On a scene I have a UIButton **_btnBuffalo** (beside others) with these coordinates in the utilities inspector:

[image]

In my ViewController I´m trying to get the buttons rect like this:

```
 CGRect btnRect = _btnBuffalo.bounds;
```

Unfortunately I´m getting this result with NSLog:

```
btnRect x: 0.000000,  y: 0.000000,  w: 160.000000,  h: 120.000000
```

I really understand why x and y are 0.000000, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call `_btnBuffalo.frame` instead of `_btnBuffalo.bounds`. `bounds`  always returns `zero origin` for any view.

Comment: Thanks a lot, frame was the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The `frame` property specifies the size and location of the view in its superview’s coordinate system.so you have to do like this.

```
CGRect btnRect = _btnBuffalo.frame;
NSLog(@"%f ,%f ,%f ,%f",btnRect.origin.x,btnRect.origin.y,btnRect.size.width,btnRect.size.height);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I did.